# Why is my Rules Component not being scheduled accurately?

Tags: rules

My aim is to send an email to new students at certain weeks after admission. E.g week 28, week 32, week 45.

I set up components with action to send email.

I configured a rule with event: after saving new content type(student).

The content type has a field - date of admission.

I scheduled component evaluation based on the offset of 'date of admission'.

So for example:

Date of admission: 02/03/13 (March 2nd 2013)

Offset: 224 days

However when the rule is triggered and I go to admin/config/workflow/rules/schedule, I noticed that the scheduled date is 16/10/13 rather than 12/10/13.

Please how can I resolve this?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're trying to achieve, what your rule does, and what conditions trigger it. Please clarify.

Comment: Question has been edited accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

When scheduling a Rules Component, you specify a value within **Scheduled evaluation date**. One of the options to do so, is to specify ***Relative dates*** like "+1 day", as mentioned within the Rules UI:

> ***... any other values in GMT known by the PHP [strtotime()](http://php.net/strtotime) function (like "+1 day")***

As per your "offset = 224 days", I'm assuming you used a value like "+224 days".

However since you want to schedule the Rules Component a certain number of weeks after admission (like "week 28, week 32, week 45."), try to specify Relative dates like "+28 weeks", "+32 weeks", "+45 weeks". That might help for the Rules Scheduler to show a more accurate date.